# Yii2 - Render form inside footer (main.php)

Tags: php, forms, model, yii2

in my main.php layout file, of Yii2, i need to render a form located in folder contacto/_form.

How can i pass the $model variable to the file main.php, inside layouts folder, and use it in:

```
<?= $this->render('_form', [
    'model' => $model,
]) ?>
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create widget like that:

```
class FormWidget extends Widget
{
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $model = ...;// code to create model

        return $this->render('_form', [
            'model' => $model
        ]);
    }
}
```

And in `layout` input widget like that:

```
<?= FormWidget::widget() ?>
```

For more read for create widgets - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-widgets.html#creating-widgets

Comment: Many Thanks, but it always throws error: Class 'Widget' not found. I put class FormWidget extends Widget, in the widget located in root/components. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok. It is working now. Many Thanks for pointing me the right way.